# Code text is missing from summaries

Tags: bug, design, search

The answer is not showing the code text in the answer summary like it use to!
I was viewing this page https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer .

The [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28138126/3041194) is missing `sails.controllers.`

In the [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28138119/3041194), it's not showing anything! It should show:
 `cp -r file /path/to/copy/file/to/is/very/deep/there`

[image: Qestion example SOmeta 284503]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Haney ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262550/haney) fixed this on Feb 9th:

> Thanks for bringing this up. I broke this intentionally a few weeks back, without properly considering the implications of my actions. It has now been fixed. Super sorry for the inconvenience! Please check now and you'll find that code once again appears in search results.

<sup>src: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248332/244519</sup>